# NuxtJS and external libraries in the head() area: How to access the script from mounted() hook?

Tags: nuxt.js

would like a second set of eyes to make sure I'm doing this the right way. I have a page in NuxtJS where I am loading an external script like so:

> Filename: `_title.vue`

```
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.photo.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.photo.description
        }
      ],
      script: [
        {
          src:
            'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious@2.1.3/dist/annotorious.min.js'
        }
      ],
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href:
            'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@recogito/annotorious@2.1.3/dist/annotorious.min.css'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Then, in my `mounted()` I initialize the script like so:

```
  mounted() {
    // Remember, mounted() is only executed on the client
    this.anno = window.Annotorious.init({
      image: this.photo.id
    })
```

**Question: is `window` the best way to do this so I can access the script throughout my page? I don't need SSR for this and I don't need to access it from any other page. Just this `_title.vue` page.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When embedding the script like that, `window` is the only option.

I tend to suggest `npm` packages and page-level (or component-level) imports whenever possible though to avoid using `window`, as well as reducing the loading time of the page because the script is already bundled (smaller + "quicker" to load).

Comment: Thanks, I agree, however, I get a `window not defined` when doing it that way.

Comment: in `mounted`, window should always be defined as `mounted` is only executed on client side (as you already mentioned). Are you sure that the error comes from the call in mounted?

Comment: Navigating to the page works. But, if I refresh, I get that error. Mounted code now: ```  async mounted() {
    // await this.getPhotoDoc()
    this.anno = new Annotorious({
      image: this.photo.id
    })

Comment: ah! Then the dependency itself could use window during initialization. See https://deltener.com/blog/common-problems-with-the-nuxt-client-only-component/ for further info

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to work better, but have another question about passing a parameter with that method. I'll make another question., Thanks!